# How to create a hierarchy in Cumulocity?

Tags: cumulocity

I have a question regarding Cumulocity. I want to create a site hierarchy in Cumulocity, we can go up to sub-tenant level only but I want to create a hierarchy up to 2 level.

Let's take an example of schools, its locations, and different branches. Here I want to attach an owner with each branch and that owner should be able to register only their own users and devices. I was trying to achieve it using groups, roles etc but was not able to do it. If anyone can suggest how to proceed for this use case.

I can see two possible options using which this can be tried:

1. Groups
2. Custom Apps (Angular apps)

But I am not sure how to proceed as there is no direct UI for the user to group assignment and REST API for this assignment is giving me errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inventory permissions for configuring access rights that are limited to a certain group [see documentation](https://cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/administration/#managing-users)

The managing of only your own users can be achieved by giving a user the global permission for USER_MANAGEMENT_CREATE. Make sure to revoke the ADMIN and READ role as well.

I would not recommend to solve this with apps on the UI side. That way you can of course hide information from the user but he may still be access it via API. Only with the RBAC you can really ensure on API level that the access is managed correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do it using RBAC.